# Edges of the graph

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, edges

In order to find the kind of the edges of a graph, at which we applied the Depth-first search algorithm, we could use this:

tree edges: x -> y when [d[y],f[y]] ⊂ [d[x],f[x]]

forward edges:  x -> y when [d[x],f[x]] ⊂ [d[y],f[y]]

back edges:  x -> y    when [d[y],f[y]] ⊂ [d[x],f[x]]

Cross edges:  x -> y   when  [d[x],f[x]] ∩ [d[y],f[y]]=∅

*Discovery Time*: The discovery time d[v] is the number of nodes discovered or finished before first seeing v.

*Finishing Time*: The finishing time f[v] is the number of nodes discovered or finished before finishing the expansion of $v$.

That's the graph I am looking at:

[image]

And here are the discovery and finish times I found:

[image]

Algorithm:

```
Depthfirstsearch(G)
   for each v ∈ V
        color[v]=white
        p[v]=NIL
   time=0
   for each v ∈ V
       if color[v]=white then
          Visit(v)


Visit(u)
  color[u]=gray
  time=time+1
  d[u]=time
  for each v ∈ Adj[u]
       if color[v]=white then
          p[v]=u
          Visit(v)
  color[u]=black
  time=time+1
  f[u]=time
```

When we have for example the case [d[y],f[y]] ⊂ [d[x],f[x]] how can we know if it is a tree  edge or a back edge?

Do we have to  mark the parent of each node, like that:

[image]

and if there is red edge we know that it is a tree edge? If so, could you explain me why?

Also, aren't  jh,ia forward edges and ag a back edge? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationships for forward and back edges are incorrect - you should exchange them.
Apart from that, I would recommend reading this paragraph from wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search
it includes a more intuitive and straightforward definition of those edges and a good picture:
[image]

### Direct answers to your questions

> When we have for example the case [d[y],f[y]] ⊂ [d[x],f[x]] how can we
>   know if it is a tree edge or a *forward* edge?

If an edge belongs to the tree - it is a tree edge (and all tree edges fulfill the relationship above).
If an edge doesn't belong to the tree **and** it fulfills the relationship above - it is a forward edge.

> Do we have to mark the parent of each node, like that: [...] and if there is red edge we know that it is a tree edge?

Yes, however we need to remember that tree edges are blue and red edges are just a representation of the tree and they point in the other direction. So, if there is a red arrow `x -> y`, it means that a blue arrow `y -> x` belongs to the tree (it may be obvious for you). You may also read the definition of the spanning tree:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Definitions

> Also, aren't jh,ia forward edges and ag a back edge? Or am I wrong?

It's exactly the other way around: jh,ia are back edges and ag is a forward edge (because your relationships for back and forward edges are incorrect).

### Longer explanation

When you run DFS on a graph, it produces a representation of a spanning tree of this graph by setting `p[v]=u` in `Visit(u)` (which means that vertex `u` is a parent of vertex `v` in the spanning tree of the input graph).

You have correctly drawn this representation using red arrows. However, what actually forms the spanning tree of a graph are the edges of this graph (or a subset of them to be precise). So, to know if a blue `x -> y` edge of the graph belongs to the spanning tree of this graph, we need to check if there is an `y -> x` red edge in your picture or, in other words, if `x` is a parent of `y` (`p[y] == x`) in the spanning tree.

Let's find out why `jh` is a back edge. We need to look at your second picture:

[image: DFS]

The DFS starts in `a`. After it has visited vertexes `c,f,g` it backtraces to `a` and visits  `d` for the first time (which adds edge a -> d to the spanning tree the DFS is building). Then, it visits `h,j` and now it wants to visit `h` but it's already been visited and `h` has a smaller discovery time than `j`, so we are moving back - it is a back edge.

Comment: I see... But could you explain me further why  if x is a parent of y, then the edge x->y is a tree edge?

Comment: Also, the exercise I am looking at asks me to show how depth-first search works on a graph. So do I have to write the commands that are executed or do I have just to write at the nodes the discovery and finishing times and add the red arrows at the graph?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what a tree and a spanning tree in particular are? Forget about the parent for a moment and take a look at 3rd page of this pdf (there is a definition of a tree edge): http://www.cs.kau.se/cs/education/courses/dvgb03/lectures/graphs2.pdf  
In your exercise you need to draw a picture like the one I pasted from wikipedia - just write discovery times for vertices and mark edges as tree/forward/back/cross. If you can draw it, it shows that you know how DFS works.

Comment: Could you also take a look at this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28005030/how-can-we-find-the-initial-node-in-order-to-apply-the-algorithm