# How can we find the initial node in order to apply the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

Consider the following graph G and consider that at an execution of the algorithm DFS at G, the edges of the graph are characterized as tree edges(t), back edges(b)  , forward edges(f) and cross edges(c) as at the following graph. For each node of the graph find the discovery time and the finishing time of the node.
In other words, for each node v of the graph, find the values d[v] and f[v] that associates  the algorithm DFS with this node.

[image]

Notice that there is only one possible assignment of the values d[v] and f[v].

Could you give me a hint how we can find the initial node in order to start applying the Depth first search algorithm?

Comment: do you know your question is in the book "Introduction to Algorithm"?

Comment: @qqibrow I didn't find it at the chapter of Depth first search? Where did you see it? :/

Comment: It's in the end of this chapter. I am using second edition.

Comment: @qqibrow I haven't this edition... :/ I have the first one... Could you maybe send me a  difficult exercise of your version that is related to the Dijkstra's algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at node `a` - what could DFS do in node `a`? It could go either to `b` or `e`. We see that it chose `b`, because `a->b` is a tree edge and `a->e` is a forward edge (check the definition of tree/forward edge). In `b` the only choice was to visit `f`. In `f` DFS could go either to `a`, `e` or `g`. We can assume that it tried to visit `a` (`f->a` is marked as back edge, so everything is correct until now), than it visited `e` and than tried to visit `b`. However, we now have a problem with edge `f->g`. It is marked as a cross edge, which means that DFS had already visited `g` before. Otherwise, this edge would have been marked as a tree edge. So, we know that `a` was not the initial node. We need to try other options. What about `c`? Again, all of edges coming out of `c` are marked as cross, not tree, so `c` was not the initial node.

What about `d`? If DFS started in `d`, it could go from `d` to `g` and that's what happened because `d->g` is marked as tree edge. There were no nodes to go from `g` so it backtraced to `d` and visited `h`. From `h` it tried to visit `g` but it has already visited earlier, so `h->g` is marked as cross - correct. Great, so `d` was the initial node for this DFS execution. After visiting a connected component which contains `d`, `g` and `h`, DFS could start again either from `a` or `c` but we already know that it has not started from `c` because of those cross edges. So it started from `a` and after visiting `b`, `f` and `e` it started from `c`.

Comment: So, we don't start from a, because if we would, after having reached f we would have to go to g, but (f,g) is a cross edge, right?
Also, why is d->g->h a connected component, although there is no path from h->g ?

Furthermore, if we have an edge from x to y, that is a cross edge, we know that y was already been visited, right? If the edge is a tree edge, we know that y wasn't already been visited visited, right?
What can we conclude if we have a back edge or a forward edge?

Comment: "So, we don't start from a, because [...] right?" - right. "Also, why is d->g->h a connected component [...]?" - Hmm, sorry, I was not precise, connected components are in undirected graphs from definition. I just meant that DFS couldn't go anywhere after visiting d,g,h (starting from d), because there are no other edges going out of those nodes, so it had to choose a different node of the graph and start from that node.

Comment: Concerning different types of edges - I have pasted a picture and tried to explain them to you in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484803/edges-of-the-graph... If you are not just applying DFS to a given graph, but you get a result of DFS and want to reconstruct how it worked, you just need to simulate the DFS starting from different nodes and see if you get the same results. Tree edges are the edges that DFS follows and reaches an unvisited node. Back edge is an edge to a visited node which is ancestor of current node in the tree.

Comment: Forward edge is an edge to a visited node which is a descendant of current node in the tree and cross edges point to visited nodes which are neither descendants nor ancestors of current node in the tree.

Comment: You give good explanations..!!! Thanks a lot!!! Could you maybe also take a look at this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1111027/show-that-the-dijkstras-algorithm-computes-correctly-the-shortest-paths

Answer (score 0):

Tree edges should form a forest. A node at wich the DFS could have started is a node that has no incoming tree edges.

Comment: Could you explain me why the node at which the DFS started is the node that has no incoming tree edges?

Comment: "Tree edges should form a tree." - wrong, they may form a forest and that's the case here.

Comment: @MD-11 wrongly assumed that the graph is connected. fixed.